# Screen Flow - Convert Collection Variable into single Id

Tags: visual-workflow, collection-variable

I have built a Screen Flow which has an upload file component, which I have limited to one file per Flow process.

The output of this component is called "Content Document IDs" and required to be stored in a Text Collection Variable, which effectively is an Array of the uploaded file Id's.

[image]

The problem is that although the collection variable is only returning one Id, I cannot access it, as it returns the value as an array - [xxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

[image]

**UPDATE:**
As the formula is returning the ID as an Array - [xxxxxxxxxxx] I have removed the brackets, leaving just the Id...

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({!DocumentIds},'[',''),']','')
```

Is this the only way to do this? It seems a bit fiddly??

Comment: We never got to see the formula... how would we know what was wrong to begin with?

Comment: Fair point! I've updated the question/update to be a bit more helpful to others.

Comment: The "official" way would involve using a loop/assignment pair, but that really seems like overkill. I actually think the formula is a lot easier, if not a bit "fiddly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by sfdcfox in the comments section, using a loop/assignment is the "proper" way to dissect the array into the individual Ids. The following link supports a similar scenario:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DX3nQAG

That being said, using a formula to remove the array brackets also works...